# Error: ODI-10244 Can not Import SNP_PROFMATH View

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-data-integrator

I install ODI 12c (12.2.1.3.0) and I get the following error while creating the Master repo.

oracle.odi.setup.RepositorySetupException: com.sunopsis.core.SnpsForeignKeyReferencedObjectMissingException: ODI-10244: Cannot import SNP_PROFMETH View (with global id: a45bc09f-660d-37ed-b84c-4c771abc66c3 and internal id: 24999 | 42000) because referenced SNP_PROFİLE with global id null does not exist.
at oracle.odi.setup.support.MasterRepositorySetupImpl.internalCreateMaster(MasterRepositorySetupImpl.java:634)
at oracle.odi.setup.support.MasterRepositorySetupImpl.internalCreateMaster(MasterRepositorySetupImpl.java:464)
at oracle.odi.setup.support.MasterRepositorySetupImpl.createMasterRepository(MasterRepositorySetupImpl.java:1103)
at oracle.odi.setup.support.MasterRepositorySetupImpl.createMasterRepository(MasterRepositorySetupImpl.java:1004)
at oracle.odi.ui.gallery.support.MasterCreateRepositoryPage.invoke(MasterCreateRepositoryPage.java:269)
at oracle.odi.ui.gallery.support.AbstractMasterRepositoryWizard$2.run(AbstractMasterRepositoryWizard.java:168)
at oracle.ide.dialogs.ProgressBar.run(ProgressBar.java:961)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.sunopsis.core.SnpsForeignKeyReferencedObjectMissingException: ODI-10244: Cannot import SNP_PROFMETH View (with global id: a45bc09f-660d-37ed-b84c-4c771abc66c3 and internal id: 24999 | 42000) because referenced SNP_PROFİLE with global id null does not exist.
at com.sunopsis.dwg.DwgDuplicationTools.processFkRefThatCannotBeSet(DwgDuplicationTools.java:6831)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.DwgDuplicationTools.setFkRefsUsingFkXRefs(DwgDuplicationTools.java:7064)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.DwgDuplicationTools.setFkRefsUsingFkXRefs(DwgDuplicationTools.java:6843)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.DwgDuplicationTools.importOtherObjects(DwgDuplicationTools.java:4780)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.DwgDuplicationTools.synonymImport(DwgDuplicationTools.java:4034)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.DwgObject.importFromObjectLst(DwgObject.java:9950)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.DwgObject.internalImportObjectList(DwgObject.java:8660)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.DwgObject.doImport(DwgObject.java:9140)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.DwgObject.importFromXml(DwgObject.java:7575)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.DwgObject.internalImportFromXmlWithCommit(DwgObject.java:7695)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.DwgObject.importFromXmlWithCommit(DwgObject.java:7898)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.DwgObject.importFromXmlWithCommit(DwgObject.java:7864)
at com.sunopsis.dwg.DwgObject.importFromXmlWithCommit(DwgObject.java:7823)
at com.sunopsis.repository.manager.RepositoryManager.importObjectsUsingImportFromXML(RepositoryManager.java:7703)
at com.sunopsis.repository.manager.RepositoryManager.treatObjectList(RepositoryManager.java:5129)
at com.sunopsis.repository.manager.RepositoryManager.masterRepositoryImport(RepositoryManager.java:4117)
at com.sunopsis.repository.manager.RepositoryManager.masterRepositoryImport(RepositoryManager.java:3880)
at com.sunopsis.repository.manager.RepositoryManager.masterRepositoryCreation(RepositoryManager.java:2130)
at oracle.odi.setup.support.MasterRepositorySetupImpl.internalCreateMaster(MasterRepositorySetupImpl.java:626)
... 7 more

Why is that, and how can I fix my problem?